# In windows how to iterate over given directory and do replace operation in file using batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

For a given directory, How to find `.java file` in **current** and **sub-directory** and verify if the file containing *"com.demo"* then replace with *"com.practice"* in Windows bat command?
Assumptions:
OS: Windows 10
After doing lot of google I came to below command but it neither throwing error nor doing anything.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("<my direcoty path>*.java") do (
  type %%f | repl "com.demo" "com.practice" >%%f.new
move %%f.new %%f
  set /p val=<%%f
  echo %val%
  echo "fullname: %%f"   
  echo "name: %%~nf"
  echo "contents: !val!"


)

pause
```

Comment: use `for /r` for recursive. `set /p val=<%%f` gets the first line of the file only. Instead of `echo %val%`, I think you meant `echo !val!` And you should use quotes around `%%f` to avoid syntax errors with files that have a space in their name.

Comment: `for /r "<my directory path>" %%f in ("*.java") do ...`

Comment: `for /r "D:\workspace\poc\nishant1" %%f in ("*.java") do
  set /p val=<%%f
   type "%%f" | repl "%com.demo" "%com.practice" >"%%f".new
move "%%f".new "%%"f
  echo !val!
  echo "fullname: %%f"   
  echo "name: %%~nf"
  echo "contents: !val!"
)`<br> Tried above still not working.

Comment: define "not working".

Comment: What command is `repl`? since this is not available in `cmd` by default you must have installed something; please share the related source (by [edit]ing your question)...

Comment: @aschipfl, perhaps, it's a version of [this superseded batch file](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855)!